# iOS, ARC: Background thread freezes UI

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uiimagepickercontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a *UIViewController* with a *UITableView* as subview. When a certain cell was clicked an *UIImagePickerController* should be presented. Because of the long initialization time it takes, I perfom this process in the background when the *UIViewController* did appear.
Now I added ARC to my project and then it didn't still work. The UI was freezed by the initial process.

Here's my code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initImagePickerControllerInBackground) withObject:nil];
}

...

- (void)initImagePickerController
{
    if (imagePickerController != nil)
        return;

    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
}

- (void)initImagePickerControllerInBackground
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        [self initImagePickerController];
    }
}
```

What should I change to get it working for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIKit is not a thread safe class and should not be called from outside the main thread. You should not perform this UIImagePickerController allocation/interaction in the background.

Comment: Ok. And what's your suggestion? Should I initialize it when the app starts?

Comment: A UIImagePicker is a bit of a heavyweight (as you've seen), relatively slow to init and uses lots of memory. For those reasons, you generally want to create it close to where you'll need it - and so probably not at app launch. How much does the app focus on the imagePicker? Is it a major or minor component? If you'll use it a lot, over and over, I'd start it with your tableView (just not in the background). Another suggestion would be: Load it lazily the first time the user opts to update an image, and maybe move the action to a detail screen with a button, vs. direct from cell tap/selection.

Comment: I think in general users may expect a delay when pressing a button to "choose" an image. I think they don't expect a delay when selecting a row from a tableView (hence, my suggestion to move it to a button on a detail view).

Comment: It's a major component in the app. But I'm going to show an indicator view when the UIImagePickerController will be init. Thanks!